# Why can't we mutate prototype of Built-in Function Constructors?

Tags: javascript

```
String.prototype = {}; 
String.prototype;   //returns original value, i.e hasn't changed


function my_func(){}; 
my_func.prototype = {};   
my_func.prototype;  // returns {}, i.e has changed.
```

Why hasn't String.prototype changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change it because the `prototype` property of `String` is non-writable and non-configurable per the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype) which states:

> String.prototype
>   The initial value of String.prototype is the intrinsic object %StringPrototype%.
>
> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false )

Your own object's prototype *is* writable which you can see with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`:

```js
// String
console.log("String",
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String, 'prototype'))

// Custom Object
function my_func(){}; 
console.log("Your own object", 
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(my_func, 'prototype'))
```

Writable means:

> writable
>   true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed (data descriptors only).

You also can't make it writable because it is non-configurable:

> configurable
>   true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.

From: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

This doesn't mean you can't change the prototype object, you just can't delete or replace it with something else. For example you can add to it (not that I'm recommending this):

```js
String.prototype.init = function (){
  return this.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()
}
h = "hello"
console.log(h.init())
```

Comment: Reference in the spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling I added that to the answer.